# CALayer contents spread animation

Tags: ios, calayer, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I have a CALayer in which Its contents are changed time to time. When new contents appear I want it to be appeared as spreading over old one. Suggest me a possible way.

Comment: What do you mean by spreading over old one? Do you mean the size be bigger?

Comment: What causing them to change?

Comment: I change the value of contents property

Comment: Please share a code to help make it clear